# munin-limits error, Missing configuration options for contact admin; skipping

Tags: munin

I am getting an error when trying to configure email alerts with Munin. I've tried with both version 1.4.7 and 2.0.6.

My config file:

```
contacts admin
contact.admin.command mail -s "Munin notification ${var:host}" admin@company.com
contact.admin.always_send warning critical

[Production;server1]
    use_node_name yes
    address server1addr
    contacts enielson
```

The error,

```
2012/08/31 16:47:24 [WARNING] Missing configuration options for contact admin; skipping
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Turns out contacts must be defined before any host definitions. The example host (localhost) at the top of the config file was causing the the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in comments by jjames, contacts must be defined before hosts. The default munin.conf has a localhost host definition. If you add a new contact at the end of the file you will see this error. To fix remove the example localhost host definition.